# UI using OpenGL ES in BB10

Tags: c++, user-interface, opengl-es, blackberry-10

I want to draw button, menu etc. (UI related things) using OpenGL ES in BB10.
How I can accomplish this task?? Any source code reference, tutorial or developer guide will be highly appriciated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am also in state of developing my own library of UI. I draw it using `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` to form a quads, two of it including the boarder. You should have a base class included all rectangles attributes since most of UI are drawn rectangular. Just some advice.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Gameplay](http://gameplay3d.org) - the open-source cross-platform 3D engine that is aimed at the indie game developer ecosystem. It also comes with the [UI components](https://github.com/blackberry/GamePlay/wiki/User-Interface).